# Pixel 2 XL (Android 10) to Samsung Galaxy S8+ (Android 9) SMS_RECEIVED not firing instead CPIM-MESSAGE

Tags: android, sms

My app uses android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED to detect incoming SMS.

Today find that SMS from Pixel 2 XL (running Android 10, T-Mobile) to a Samsung Galaxy S8+ (running Android 9, T-Mobile) do not cause SMS_RECEIVED to fire. (SMS from other phones--also on T-Mobile--works as expected)

Instead I see this in Logcat (the message content is "Tls xdert"). I think this is related to the brave new world of RCS? I would like to know how to intercept these messages, in the absence of SMS_RECEIVED

```
    2019-11-11 10:13:15.068 4725-5129/? D/SIPMSG[0]: MESSAGE sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@[2607:fc20:6509:483:0:19:f4ff:7401]:6300 SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/TCP [FD00:976A:D5D3:30::1]:65529;branch=z9hG4bKg3Zqkv7ixhis1q8w417wbtyipw26hxymf
    Max-Forwards: 68
    To: <sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@msg.pc.t-mobile.com>
    From: <sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@msg.pc.t-mobile.com>;tag=h7g4Esbg_mavodi-d-8f-d9-1-88-_FA163E30535A-7135-a262f700-39fa83-5dc97a89-c6ad2
    Call-ID: FA163E30535A-7135-a262f700-39fa82-5dc97a89-c6a8d~rmso(20-136-136-8-0-0-1)~rmst(13-137-138-2-3-0-1)
    CSeq: 1 MESSAGE
    Expires: 259200
    Allow: MESSAGE, INVITE, ACK, NOTIFY, OPTIONS, SUBSCRIBE, BYE, REFER, UPDATE, REGISTER, CANCEL
    Content-Type: message/cpim
    User-Agent: IM-serv/OMA1.0 Mavenir Rms/v7.2
    Request-Disposition: no-queue
    P-Asserted-Identity: <sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@msg.pc.t-mobile.com>
    Accept-Contact: *;+g.3gpp.icsi-ref="urn%3Aurn-7%3A3gpp-service.ims.icsi.oma.cpm.msg";explicit;require
    P-Called-Party-ID: <sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@msg.pc.t-mobile.com>
    P-Charging-Vector: icid-value=pmp4.nyatf201.sip.t-mobile.co-1573-485194-306614-723;icid-generated-at=pmp4.nyatf201.sip.t-mobile.com
    X-Mav-Service-Done: Done
    P-Mav-Smpp-Seq-Num: 3775214
    P-Mav-Smpp-Datacoding: 0
    P-Mav-Skipdb: True, True
    Direction: In
    Conversation-Id: 47d5d913-ff7f2538-5dc97a89-c67a1
    Contribution-Id: 47d5d913-ff7f2538-5dc97a89-c67a1
    Content-Length: 350

    From: sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@msg.pc.t-mobile.com
    DateTime: 2019-11-11T07:13:13PST.
    NS: imdn <urn:ietf:params:imdn>
    imdn.Message-ID: smstmous__253_74940eb8-ff973104-5dc97a89-c67ad
    imdn.Disposition-Notification: positive-delivery, display
    To: sip:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@msg.pc.t-mobile.com

    Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    Content-length: 9

    Tls xdert
2019-11-11 10:13:15.070 4725-5129/? D/[IMS6.0]: CpimWrapper::CpimWrapper(): CPIM-MESSAGE: [From: sip:+12223334444@msg.pc.t-mobile.com
    DateTime: 2019-11-11T07:13:13PST.
    NS: imdn <urn:ietf:params:imdn>
    imdn.Message-ID: smstmous__253_74940eb8-ff973104-5dc97a89-c67ad
    imdn.Disposition-Notification: positive-delivery, display
    To: sip:+14445556666@msg.pc.t-mobile.com

    Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    Content-length: 9

    Tls xdert]
2019-11-11 10:13:15.071 4725-5129/? D/[IMS6.0]: CpimWrapper::CpimWrapper(): CPIM-MESSAGE content : [Tls xdert]
2019-11-11 10:13:15.086 4725-5129/? D/[IMS6.0]: CpimWrapper::CpimWrapper(): CPIM-MESSAGE: [From: sip:+12223334444@msg.pc.t-mobile.com
    DateTime: 2019-11-11T07:13:13PST.
    NS: imdn <urn:ietf:params:imdn>
    imdn.Message-ID: smstmous__253_74940eb8-ff973104-5dc97a89-c67ad
    imdn.Disposition-Notification: positive-delivery, display
    To: sip:+14445556666@msg.pc.t-mobile.com

    Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    Content-length: 9

    Tls xdert]
2019-11-11 10:13:15.087 4725-5129/? D/[IMS6.0]: CpimWrapper::CpimWrapper(): CPIM-MESSAGE content : [Tls xdert]
```

Comment: As a result of RCS availability in fits and starts, and lack of API, I fear there will be a long period where SMS handling apps will seem broken